# What is the wrong in that easy python code?

Tags: python

```
my_list = input("Enter a list of numbers separated by space")
my_list = my_list.split(' ')
counter = 0
for i in my_list:
    if i == 4:
        counter = counter + 1
print('the count is ', counter)
```

The expected output is how many times the number 4 occurs in the list. The actual output is zero no matter what the input is.

Comment: Do you mean that it is always `0`?  If it's always saying `0`, it's because you're comparing different types:  `4 != "4"`

Comment: Your list is made of strings, convert them to integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some answerers already pointed out, you're trying to compare 4 with '4'. Here are you options:

**1)** Cast `i` to string. But make sure, that your script doesn't crash in case of non-integer input:

```
my_list = input("Enter a list of numbers separated by space")
my_list = my_list.split(' ')
counter = 0
for i in my_list:
    try:
        i = int(i)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    if i == 4:
        counter = counter + 1

print('the count is ', counter)
```

**2)** `4` is hardcoded. You could use just `'4'` instead of `4`

```
my_list = input("Enter a list of numbers separated by space")
my_list = my_list.split(' ')
counter = 0
for i in my_list:
    try:
        i = int(i)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    if i == '4':
        counter = counter + 1

print('the count is ', counter)hth
```

**3)** You don't really need a for loop to count symbols:

```
my_list = input("Enter a list of numbers separated by space")
my_list = my_list.split(' ')
counter = my_list.count('4')

print('the count is ', counter)
```

Or even so, but it gives a bit different result for cases like `'a4a 4'`:

```
input_value = input("Enter a list of numbers separated by space")

print('the count is ', input_value.count('4'))
```

Answer (score 3):

`my_list` is a list of *strings*.

```py
>>> '4' != 4
True
```

The string `'4'` is not equivalent to the integer `4`.

```py
>>> my_list = input("Enter a list of numbers separated by space")
1 42 3 5 4
>>> my_list = my_list.split(' ')
>>> my_list
['1', '42', '3', '5', '4']
>>> for i in my_list:
...     if i == 4:
...         print("It's 4!")
>>> for i in my_list:
...     if int(i) == 4:
...         print("It's 4!")
It's 4!
```

You need to convert `i` to an `int` in your check for equality with `4`. You can do this with the function [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

The other alternative is to [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) `int` over the list of strings.

```py
>>> for i in map(int, my_list):
...     if i == 4:
...         print("It's 4!")
It's 4!
```

Comment: print('It's 4!') # You should use double or triple quotes.

Comment: @pat_brat I'm sorry, you are right. I wrote this up manually. :P

Answer (score 0):

They are all in string so you need to convert them into integers

Answer (score 0):

line 5. You should put '4' instead of just 4 because 4 is integer and the list is made of strings. So you can't expect that a programe will look for integers in a string "group".